# Cassandra Node Leaving is very slow

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to remove a cassandra node. I want to increase speed of leaving process since my cluster is not busy.

I have 1 TB data to be delivered but when i check netsent data it is 25 MBps. Is there any chance to speed up?

Answer (score 3):

> I have 1 TB data to be delivered but when i check netsent data it is 25 MBps. Is there any chance to speed up?

**nodetool setstreamingthroughput XXX** where XXX is the speed in Mb/sec